# Facebook Marketing API Campaign Start & End Date

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I am able to get the campaign insights such as campaign name, reach, video views using the Facebook marketing API, but I am not able to get **Campaign Start and Campaign END date**.

```
     $fields = array(
  CampaignFields::NAME,
  CampaignFields::OBJECTIVE,
  CampaignFields::STATUS,

);

$campaigns = $account->getCampaigns($fields);
?>

  <?php

foreach ($campaigns as $campaign) {
//---------------------------------
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $campaign->id; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $campaign->name; ?></td>

<?php
$fields = array (
    'reach',    
    'impressions',
    'website_clicks',
    'cpm',
    'video_10_sec_watched_actions',
    'video_avg_sec_watched_actions',
);  

$params = array (
    'date_preset'=>'last_30_days',
    'data_columns'=>"['adgroup_id','actions','reach']",
);

?>


<?php

$campaign = new Campaign($campaign->id);
$insights = $campaign->getinsights($fields, $params);

foreach ($insights as $insight) {
        echo '<td>'.$insight->reach. '</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$insight->impressions. '</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$insight->website_clicks. '</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$insight->cpm. '</td>';
//        echo '<td>'.$insight->video_10_sec_watched_actions. '</td>';
//        echo '<td>'.$insight->video_avg_sec_watched_actions. '</td>';
//      
}
        // find video views
        $videoview = 0;
//        $postEngagement = -1;
    printf('<td>%s</td>', $insight->video_10_sec_watched_actions[0]['value']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get Campaign Start and Campaign END date use `"START_TIME"` and `"STOP_TIME"` Fields.

```
$fields = array(
    CampaignFields::NAME,
    CampaignFields::OBJECTIVE,
    CampaignFields::STATUS,
    CampaignFields::CREATED_TIME,
    CampaignFields::START_TIME,
    CampaignFields::STOP_TIME,
    CampaignFields::UPDATED_TIME,
);
```

[Campaign Fields](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group#Reading)

Comment: I get an error: InvalidArgumentException: START_TIME is not a field of FacebookAds\Object\Campaign

Comment: May be your getting that issue due to API version or old SDK

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Just one more question. I am getting start_time as 2016-07-12T17:35:11+0800;  Is it possible to get only date and without displaying time.

Comment: Use php `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2016-07-12T17:35:11+0800'))` function to convert that format according to your requirements

Comment: Thanks, If I want to display the Ad-set name & ID and Ad name and ID for each campaign. How can I do that